# Using jquery/JS/CSS how do I append words to a sentence so the sentence is pushed up word by word

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, append

Instead of going left to right, I'd like the sentence being append to, to move right to left, while being pushed upwards.  Check out at my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqFL/4/) ;)...

```
                                      <-- Essentially I want the words to just get pu
-shed in this direction <------------------------------------------------------------
------- <-- as I continue to append more and more words to the end of this #span. Like 
a screw just being unscrewed...?
```

Comment: i dont understand this correctly.. do you want the rest of the works to be in line below "<-- ME"?

Comment: I want  "<-- ME" to get pushed to the left and up by newly appended words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use element `div` inside the paragraph. The `div` should have a `width` or a `left-margin`

It can looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/wmqFL/3/. If you want you can creae the `div` dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand ur answer.  "Me" doesn't get pushed left and up. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/wmqFL/4/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to p(CSS):-

```
p {
    text-align:right;
}
```

HTML:-

```
<button id="Append">Add Text</button>

<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

JQUERY:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Append").click(function(){
    $("p").append("<span> Word </span>");
  });
});
```

Check this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqFL/8/)

Comment: No this goes down, and not up.  I need the words in the sentence <-------- to get pushed up and left.